# Arduino function parameters

Tags: c++, arduino

Code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Ucglib.h"

Ucglib_ILI9341_18x240x320_HWSPI ucg(/*cd=*/ 8, /*cs=*/ 7, /*reset=*/ 5);

void functionBar()
{
  ucg.begin(UCG_FONT_MODE_TRANSPARENT);
  ucg.clearScreen();

  ucg.setRotate270();

  ucg.setColor(94, 88, 107);
  ucg.drawBox(0,0, 320, 20);

  ucg.setColor(255,255, 255);
  ucg.setFont(ucg_font_9x18_tf);
  frm("Blitz OS", 0);
  
  
}

void frm(string a, int b)
{
  int width = ucg.getStrWidth(a);
  ucg.setPrintPos(width, 15);
  ucg.print(a);
}
```

Error:

```
FunctionBar:23:10: error: variable or field 'frm' declared void
 void frm(string a, int b)
          ^~~~~~
FunctionBar:23:10: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
D:\Users\ALMA\Desktop\Blitz OS\Setup\FunctionBar.ino:23:10: note: suggested alternative: 'String'
 void frm(string a, int b)
          ^~~~~~
          String
FunctionBar:23:20: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void frm(string a, int b)
                    ^~~
D:\Users\ALMA\Desktop\Blitz OS\Setup\FunctionBar.ino: In function 'void functionBar()':
FunctionBar:18:3: error: 'frm' was not declared in this scope
   frm("Blitz OS", 0);
   ^~~
D:\Users\ALMA\Desktop\Blitz OS\Setup\FunctionBar.ino:18:3: note: suggested alternative: 'free'
   frm("Blitz OS", 0);
   ^~~
   free
D:\Users\ALMA\Desktop\Blitz OS\Setup\FunctionBar.ino: At global scope:
FunctionBar:23:10: error: variable or field 'frm' declared void
 void frm(string a, int b)
          ^~~~~~
FunctionBar:23:10: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
D:\Users\ALMA\Desktop\Blitz OS\Setup\FunctionBar.ino:23:10: note: suggested alternative: 'String'
 void frm(string a, int b)
          ^~~~~~
          String
FunctionBar:23:20: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void frm(string a, int b)
                    ^~~
exit status 1
variable or field 'frm' declared void
```

I have no idea why, but it doesn't let me add another parameter after the string a.

Comment: what is `string`? Arduino has `String` or `const char*`

Comment: It worked with ```const char*``` thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the parameter in `ucg.getStrWidth` is `const char*`. So use this type as a parameter in your function too.